# Python Sphinx docstrings - reference parameter block multiple times

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring

I've got multiple classes that all have a base they inherit from. The `__init__` has a ton of parameters for each that are all basically the same. Is there anyway in the docstrings with sphinx to just write the param definition once, then reference everywhere else?

For example:

```
:param str a: Opt A
:param str b: Opt B
:param str c: Opt C
```

In all classes that inherit from the base I want the same param block as shown above. The main reason I want to do this is that in reality there's a dozen or more params and they may change in the future. I want to only update them one place.